# Vtiger 6 - customize login page

Tags: vtiger

Where is the login page for VTIGER 6?

I tried `/Smarty/templates`.

However, the `login.tpl` there is the old Vtiger 5.4.

I want to customize the login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To customize login page, just go to folder: *vtigercrm\layouts\vlayout\modules\Users*

- Duplicate file: **Login.Default.tpl** rename to **Login.Custom.tpl**
- You can modify it safely there

In case, you need some new images or modify them, you can go to folder: *vtigercrm\layouts\vlayout\skins\images*

Answer (score 2):

Full customization for vTiger 6 can be done via the following files:

- layouts\vlayout\modules\Users\login.tpl
- layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\header.tpl
- layouts\vlayout\skins\softed\style.css

Answer (score 0):

Its in layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/login.tpl

I doubt you are using Vtiger EA version. Use the stable version always

Answer (score 0):

in Vtiger version 6 the folder structure is changed a bit.
In new version they have moved it under layouts folder.
To modify you can edit the file layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/Login.tpl

Fore more details on new file/folder structure please check https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtiger_6_Developer_Guide#Folder_Structure

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In case of vTigerCRM 6.0 use the following file to change the login screen

layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/login.tpl

And for vTigerCRM 6.2 onwards change the following file

layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/Login.Custom.tpl

Here login.tpl checks whether the developer has the Login.Custom.tpl or not (Please check the attached screenshot[image]). Else it loads the Login.Default.tpl